# OpenGL ES 1 initialization and texture drawing in 2D iOS C++

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to initialize screen with OpenGL ES 1 and draw a simple texture. My code is ported from Windows to iOS and not working.

In init:

```
glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
glViewport(0.f, 0.f, m_width, m_height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //gl_invalid_operation error goes from here
glLoadIdentity(); // same error
glOrthof(0.f, m_width, m_height, 0.f, 1, -1); // same error
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // same error
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // invalid enum error
glLoadIdentity(); // invalid operation
```

My texture creation code is generating without problems, and then drawing code goes:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
glBegin(); // gles have no this method
glTexCoord2i(<texture coords here>);
glVertex3f(<screen coords here>);
<for each point>

glEnd(); // none in gles
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL);
```

Comment: On iOS you need to initialize the view's layer correctly to ensure GL context is available, and you'll need to tell it to use ES 1. I'd suggest starting with one of the iOS GL samples and go from there, you need that boilerplate code to get started, copying in code from another platform to a random location in an iOS app isn't going to get you very far.

Comment: According to GLES 1.1 reference guide - glMatrixMode - can't cause INVALID_OPERATION error, however - this method in OpenGL - can. Is there any possibility i'm somehow using OpenGL methods in my GLES application (i'm using SDL2, #include'd SDL2_opengles.h). maybe there is some frameworks i should not include?

Comment: i is stupid. found out what was the problem:

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 1);

here - i need to set minimum and maximum version of GLES, otherwise my GLES context was created with OpenGLES 2.0 and methods i used was from 1.1

Comment: @FertoVordalastr Do you have a small sample project that does what you describe above that would share please? I am struggling to get my Windows OpenGL code to work on iOS with OpenGL ES1 too and SDL2. I don't get any GL errors at all - my textures don't paint properly. I just get squares.

Comment: @SparkyNZ since then i've rewrote my code to gles2 and now doing Android with this. If you still need help with gles/iOS/SDL2 mail me itpuh@mail.ru